# ForeignKey error in Dynamic Table Creation in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Iam trying to create a function in which the tables are created based on the users input in sqlalchemy

This is the user input

```py
tables = [
    {
        "name": "table1",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "col1",
                "type": "integer"
            },
            {
                "name": "col2",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "col3",
                "type": "boolean"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "table2",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "col1",
                "type": "integer"
            },
            {
                "name": "col2",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "col3",
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            {
                "name": "col4",
                "type": "foreign_key",
                "related_to": "table1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my function

```py
COLUMN_TYPES = {
    'integer': Integer,
    'string': String,
    'boolean': Boolean,
}


def create_model(table_details, return_table=False):
    table_name = table_details['name']
    columns = []
    for field in table_details['fields']:
        field_name = field['name']
        field_type = field['type']

        if field_type == "foreign_key":
            columns.append(Column(field_name, Integer, ForeignKey(f'{field["related_to"]}.id')))
        else:
            columns.append(Column(field_name, COLUMN_TYPES[field_type]))
    metadata = MetaData()
    table = Table(
        table_name,
        metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        *columns
    )
    if return_table:
        return table
    try:
        metadata.create_all(engine)

        return 200
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return 400
```

The `table1` is created and it gives me `200`
But when creating `table2` I get this error

`Foreign key associated with column 'table2.col4' could not find table 'table1' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'`

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are trying yo apply foreign before creating table1 successfully, so I recommend creating tables without foreign keys and then applying the foreign keys after the creation:

```py
def create_model(table_details, return_table=False):
    table_name = table_details['name']
    columns = []
    for field in table_details['fields']:
        field_name = field['name']
        field_type = field['type']

        if field_type == "foreign_key":
            columns.append(Column(field_name, Integer))
        else:
            columns.append(Column(field_name, COLUMN_TYPES[field_type]))

    metadata = MetaData()
    table = Table(
        table_name,
        metadata,
        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
        *columns
    )

    if return_table:
        return table

    try:
        metadata.create_all(engine)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return 400

    # Add foreign key constraints after tables have been created
    for field in table_details['fields']:
        if field['type'] == 'foreign_key':
            related_table_name = field['related_to']
            related_table = metadata.tables[related_table_name]
            foreign_key = ForeignKey(f'{related_table_name}.id')
            table.append_column(Column(field['name'], Integer, foreign_key))

    try:
        metadata.create_all(engine)
        return 200
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return 400
```

Comment: need to add ```replace_existing=True``` to table.append_column